# Unable to get updated queryParams when navigating to same url

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am unable to get the updated queryParams when I come back to the same url with updated query Params.

For instance,

1. Home page -> Form '/form?test=123' . I get this queryParam.
2. Form page -> Details '/details?form=xyz'
3. Details page -> Form '/form?param1=abc' (here is am using navigateBack method of NavController). Here I dont get the updated queryParam even though I have subscribed to the queryParams

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-update-query-params?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fform%2Fform.page.ts

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Seems like you're stackblitz link doesn't work ? Says "The page you requested couldn't be found."

Comment: @KShewengger: My bad, fixed it.

Comment: Still can't be accessed :( If you clicked the stackblitz link above, would you be able to access ?

Comment: @KShewengger: My bad, not sure why its not working, created another fork and updated the link.

Comment: Most likely related to ionic. If you use `navigateRoot` instead of forward or back in your views, the issue disappears .